# Get user data using curb/Curl in Ruby

Tags: support, api, json, ruby

I am trying to get user data in my Rails app.

I am doing this:

```
  url_so = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/231917?type=jsontext"
  curl = Curl::Easy.new(url_so)
  curl.perform
  data_obj = JSON.parse(curl.body_str)
```

But, the JSON parser says its not a correct format. So, when I did a `curl.body_str` , I got this.

```
 => "\037\213\b\000\000\000\000\000\004\000\354\275\a`\034I\226%&/m\312{\177J\365J\327\340t\241\b\200`\023$\330\220@\020\354\301\210\315\346\222\354\035iG#)\253*\201\312eVe]f\026@\314\355\235\274\367\336{\357\275\367\336{\357\275\367\272;\235N'\367\337\377?\\fd\001l\366\316J\332\311\236!\200\252\310\037?~|\037?\"~\361o\234\244\351Gm\325f\345G\217\322\335\021\377\271\312.\362\360\257\246\370\001>\271\267#\037\255\233\274n\350\357\357\341\2574\375\305\362C\277\370\375\213\031}\265wo\367\341\356\203Q\370M{\275\002\230\217\352\374\242h\332\274\316g\037\271\026\323:\317\332\242Z\376.......
```

Any suggestions? How can I fetch a JSON file?

I am new to Ruby on Rails too, so is there any better gem to access the SO API?

**SOLUTION:**

This works, the problem was it was GZIP

```
  curl = Curl::Easy.new(url_so)
  curl.perform
  json_data = ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(curl.body_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're forgetting that the API only supplies **gzipped** data.

I don't use Ruby, so you'll have to figure out how to tell curl to accept gzip data.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd already forgotten this. This caused me a huge nightmare when I first set out on the API.

Comment: Link: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/gzip

Answer (score 2):

From this link: [Gzip and deflate compression in curb http driver](https://github.com/codesnik/handsoap/commit/1341d75ac8b43243d95858235fff52076980c0ad)

You can set curl.encoding = '' to make curb auto decompress response body. Like below:

```
url_so = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/231917?type=jsontext"
curl = Curl::Easy.new(url_so)

# enables both deflate and gzip compression of responses
curl.encoding = ''

curl.perform
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `Accepted-encoding` like:

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new(url_so)
curl.headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate"
curl.perform
```

Comment: didn't try this, but this also might work.

Comment: @zengr give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `?type=jsontext` parameter.

Comment: tried it, does not help

Comment: Same code works like a charm on github API: "http://github.com/api/v2/json/user/search/" + github_id

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this to learn ruby, or get a Stack Apps app up and running?

If you're looking to just get an app up, [try one of these libraries](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/ruby+library) - make life easier for yourself :)

If you're looking to learn ruby (and thus don't want to use a library), well I've never used ruby so I can't help.